# How can I use CKEditor, starting with HTML mode in stead of TEXT mode?

Tags: ckeditor

How can I use CKEditor, starting with HTML mode in stead of TEXT mode?

I want to use this source in HTML Mode,
but normally it inits in TEXT Mode...

Please let me know how to change or make it!!

Answer (score 11):

Set the Startup Mode of CKEDITOR to start in Source (HTML) Mode.

```
CKEDITOR.config.startupMode
```

Refer this [link](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.startupMode) for more details.